# Select rows having dstinct values for two fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

Pardon me for the title. I have a table like this:

[image]

There will be thousands of rows and now I want to select the rows having the same group_id but vr_debit and vr_credit values must not be equal: ie;, in the image shown, none of the rows satisfy this criteria. If there is are two rows, say, (6,500.000,0) and(6,0,600.000), I want them as the result. Hope you get the idea.

Thank you.

Comment: Dont show an image but copy/paste the sample data and format it with the code-button. On that way we are able to reuse the sample-data, e.g. in sql-fiddle.

Comment: @Schmelter: Thankz for your suggestion. Will do in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate each group using `SUM()` which is an aggregate function and filter them using `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT  GROUP_ID, SUM(vr_debit) totalDebit, SUM(vr_credit) totalCredit
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY GROUP_ID
HAVING  SUM(vr_debit) <> SUM(vr_credit)
```

if you want to get the uncalculated rows, you can join it on the subquery.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  GROUP_ID
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY GROUP_ID
            HAVING  SUM(vr_debit) <> SUM(vr_credit)
        ) b ON  a.GROUP_ID = b.GROUP_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*for both queries*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7e24/2)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
SELECT group_ID,
       vr_debit,
       vr_credit
FROM 
   dbo.TableName T1
WHERE
   EXISTS(
      SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableName T2
      WHERE T1.group_ID = T2.group_ID
      AND   T1.vr_debit <> T2.vr_debit
      AND   T1.vr_credit<> T2.vr_credit
      AND   T1.vr_debit <> T2.vr_credit
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use this option

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.test64 t
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.test64 t2
              WHERE t.group_id = t2.group_id
              HAVING SUM(t2.vr_debit) - SUM(t2.vr_credit) != 0
              )
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55de2c/1)